# How to Specify the path of the database on user's computer

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008

I have a vb.net application using sqlserver. This is the path for the .mdf and .ldf folder.

> C:\Users\GtechsLab\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\Data\Q76NXWCJ.KRJ\M4DZMYNZ.LCX\ereg..tion_238d66fc4e3734ba_0001.0006_ab794bb7e2467ae4\Data\eDatabase.mdf

Can i customize it to something like `D:\Desktop\Data\eDatabase.mdf`

Comment: What?  You want to use a database on a user's computer?  What are you trying to do here?

Comment: By User's computer, I mean the computer that my application will be installed once the user acquires my application.

Comment: PS: This is my connection string; Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\eDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

Comment: Do you expect to have a locally-installed SQL Server database on your end-user's computer?

Comment: It is shipped with my application.

Comment: Are you trying to change the deployment folder or let the user change the path at runtime? Your question is not clear. Since this appears to be a click-once deployment, the install path will change every install, and with every update, so if the DB is part of the deployment package, after an update it will be back to install state, and any data the user added / changed in the prior version is gone.

Comment: MrGadget that's my case. 1. Its a click once application. 2. The install path changes with every install (and i dont like it) 3. The data is lost after every update. How can I handle this professionally?